# Should an OpenIDE FileObject be closed after creation?

Tags: java, netbeans, openide

When creating modules on the NetBeans platform, the `FileObject` object represents a file in the virtual file system of the IDE. Creating new `FileObject`s is simple, but does NetBeans completely control the reference to the actual `File`, or should I close `FileObject` myself? My code is like this:

```
FileObject appRoot = FileUtil.getConfigRoot().getFileObject("myapp");

try {
    FileObject fo = servers.createData(filename);
    fo.setAttribute("name", "a name");
    fo.setAttribute("desc", "a description");
} catch (IOException ex) {
   throws new FileCreationException("Could not create file " + filename, ex);            
}
```

With the above code, am I leaving open some references to the actual file or should I obtains the `OutputStream` of the `FileObject` and close it manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around in the NetBeans API and source code I believe I've found the answer to my own question.

Attributes as set above are stored in a special attributes file. Each folder in the virtual file system has a hidden attributes file (`.nbattrs`) which contains the attributes stored for each `FileObject`, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE attributes PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD DefaultAttributes 1.0//EN"     
                            "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/attributes-1_0.dtd">
<attributes version="1.0">
    <fileobject name="dk-i2m-netbeans-smtpdummyservice-mailserver-1244831819713">
        <attr name="name" stringvalue="My test"/>
        <attr name="desc" intvalue="Server for testing outgoing e-mails"/>
    </fileobject>
</attributes>
```

This file is completely controlled by NetBeans and no opening or closing of input/output streams are necessary.

If however, you want to add content to the `FileObject` and not mere attributes, you will have to do it the normal Java-way of using the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` of the `FileObject` (both have a getter and setter) and remember to close the streams accordingly. e.g.

```
FileObject appRoot = FileUtil.getConfigRoot().getFileObject("myapp");

try {
    FileObject fo = servers.createData(filename);
    fo.setAttribute("name", "a name");
    fo.setAttribute("desc", "a description");

    // Lock the FileObject before writing
    FileLock lock;
    try {
        lock = fo.lock();
    } catch (FileAlreadyLockedException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        return;
    }

    try {
        OutputStream out = fo.getOutputStream(lock);
        try {
            // Write into the output stream
        } finally {
            // Remember to close the stream
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        lock.releaseLock();
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throws new FileCreationException("Could not create file " + filename, ex);            
}
```